# ArcFM v/s Network Engineer

Tags: arcfm, telecom

Which software would you prefer for a telecom GIS project and why?

I have experience with both, but I personally prefer [Telvent ArcFM](http://www.telvent-gis.com/products/arc.shtml) over [Telcordia Network Engineer](http://www.telcordia.com/products/network_eng/index.html) because of it's functionality and tighter integration with ESRI products, especially [ArcGIS Server](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisserver/index.html).

Any other opinions?

Edit:
I would like to have your views based on (but not limited to) these factors:
1. Performance
2. Scalability
3. Database Support
4. Customization options/ ease of customization
5. Interoperability with other (GIS) systems
6. Data exchange to/from other non-GIS systems (like Sharepoint, middlewares etc.)
7. Availability of a web-based offering

I am purposefully ignoring cost at this moment as I would like a completely technical aspect for the comparison.

Comment: None of the above - SpatialInfo (SpatialNET is a large intgrated solution for AutoCAD with Oracle Database) http://spatialinfo.com/products/52/64.html

Comment: Also [Advance Fiber Optics](http://www.ospinsight.com/) might be worth a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have to go back to my usual repsonse, do you need to talk/import/export with other vendors or clients or contractors? That is a big part of what you should take into consideration. If this is going to be your Enterprise Platform, then you really need to consider what you DB side is.
I would side heavily with Mapperz on the AutoCAD/Oracle side; for a large system this is a solution that is really hard to beat. But if you have cost concerns, the SQL2008 may be your RDBMS of choice, which may push you towards a ESRI based offering. In that case, I would really look at ArcFM; it his a very good reputation as a toolset and having good support for there customers.

Comment: Yes it will talk to other systems (both GIS and non-GIS).  What belief I have (based on my interaction with various people and their experience with other products), AutoCAD based solution has a steep learning curve for the end users. ESRI bags the opportunity mainly on this ground...it is so damn user friendly, most of the planners take much less time familiarizing themselves with it.

Comment: From a functional standpoint you can see that actually AutoCAD based tools have a shorter learning curve; people just think its harder from the 'CAD' perspective. A lot of 'Planners' have the ESRI snobery point of view; but when it comes to precise work; Autodesk or Bentley based tools always have that precision. Its why you don't see engineers designing in GIS. But you also want to make sure you are using the right tool for the job; and a CAD system may be over the head of many planners.